# Chance ACF Field with Javascript over a php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to write the dropdown-change into to an ACF field.
i have a ninja table with a dropdown and i added this code on dropdown:

```
<?php
    wp_register_script( 'custom-acf-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/scripts/script-js.js', ['acf-input'], '1.0.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-acf-js');

    function feldUpdate($selector,$value,$post_id){
        update_field('bewerber_einstufen', $value , $post_id ); 
    };
//feldUpdate('bewerber_notiz','eingeladen', 192);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Ninja Table Loaded initially
jQuery(document).on('ninja_table_loaded', function (event, $table, settings) {
    console.log('ninja_table_loaded');
    let changeButton = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var acfVersion = acf.get('acf_version');
    //alert(acfVersion);    
    for(let i=0; i < changeButton.length; i++){
        changeButton[i].addEventListener("change",function(){
            let rowidparent = this.parentElement.parentElement;
            let rowid = (rowidparent.querySelector("p").innerHTML);
            console.log(rowid);

            //feldUpdate('bewerber_notiz','eingeladen', rowid);
        });

    };
});
</script>
```

So how can i write the javascript code (variables) into my php function.

Kind regards, Daniel

Comment: I want to write the javascript value into the php function like this:
`document.write("<?php feldUpdate('bewerber_einstufen','eingeladen', $rowid );?>"); `

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call a PHP function directly with JavaScript like that. PHP is executed by the server and JavaScript is executed by the browser (in this context anyway)

To achieve what you want here you need to use Ajax. Which is the front-end making a http request to the server and then the server will call your PHP function and return an appropriate response.

Creating the Ajax endpoint for WordPress

```php
<?php
// functions.php

add_action('wp_ajax_call_feld_update', 'feldUpdateCallback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_call_feld_update', 'feldUpdateCallback'); // nopriv for unauthenticated users

/**
 * Ajax call for updating bewerber_einstufen field
 *
 * @return void
 */
function feldUpdateCallback(): void {
}
```

So now you have an ajax endpoint you can call from your JavaScript. Now you need to setup the front end and have WordPress create a [nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) for you, which is essentially the way you ensure the request came from the front-end of your own website.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var wp_nonce = '<?= wp_create_nonce('updating-field-nonce'); ?>';
var ajax_url = '<?= admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';

// Ninja Table Loaded initially
jQuery(document).on('ninja_table_loaded', function (event, $table, settings) {
    // your code was here
});
</script>
```

Now the JavaScript variable `wp_nonce` will have have the nonce stored in it and the `ajax_url` will have the url for ajax stored in it. This is normally achieved with [`wp_localize_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) however this is a simplified example for you.

Now you can create your ajax request like so

```js
    jQuery(document).on('ninja_table_loaded', function (event, $table, settings) {
        console.log('ninja_table_loaded');
        let changeButton = document.querySelectorAll('select');
        var acfVersion = acf.get('acf_version');
        //alert(acfVersion);    
        for(let i=0; i < changeButton.length; i++){
            changeButton[i].addEventListener("change",function(){
                let rowidparent = this.parentElement.parentElement;
                let rowid = (rowidparent.querySelector("p").innerHTML);
                console.log(rowid);
          
                // ajax request
                jQuery.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: ajax_url,
                   data: {
                      action: 'call_feld_update', // the action is set when you added wp_ajax_ at the beginning of this answer.
                      postId: rowid,
                      value: 'eingeladen',
                      nonce: wp_nonce
                   },
                   success: function (response) {
                      console.log(response);
                   }, 
                   error: function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                       console.log(errorThrown);
                   }
                });
            });
        };
    });
```

With that, WordPress will call the `feldUpdateCallback` function when the ajax request is sent. Now we update the PHP function that was created before so it can deal with that request...

```php
// functions.php

/**
 * Ajax call for for updating bewerber_einstufen field
 *
 * @return void
 */
function feldUpdateCallback(): void {
    // nonce - The key you set when sending the request from ajax
    // updating-field-nonce - The parameter for the wp_create_nonce function
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST['nonce'], 'updating-field-nonce')) {
        // The string we received does not match the nonce that was set on the front by WP 
        die('nonce validation failed');
    }
    // now you can deal with the request...
    feldUpdate(
        'bewerber_notiz',
        sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['value']), // https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/
        sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['postId'])
    );
    die('successful');
}
```

Comment: Thanks man you're the best.
The only thing i had to change was to add the function update field.
It is working really nice. There is only one problem left. So if i change to the next site of my ninja table the script doesn't work anymore i tried this code from ninja table but doesn't work:

`// Ninja Table full data loaded
$table.on('ninja_table_all_chunk_loaded', () => {
    console.log('ninja_table_all_chunk_loaded');
})`

Kind reagards, Daniel